# Some mandatory parameters are missing ("id") to generate a URL for route

Tags: javascript, php, symfony

I use FOSJsRoutingBundle for generate routing in javascript

this is my route in my routing.yml :

```
my_url:
    pattern:  /app/edit/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: GedApp:Default:edit }
    options:
        expose: true
```

in my javascript I have this link :

```
window.location.href = Routing.generate('my_url', { id: 13});
```

What is the problem ??

Comment: What is the value of `value`? Have you tried with a hard-coded input, e.g. `{ id: 42 }`?

Comment: value is a number, anyway I update my question.
Yes I tried with a hard-coded but the same error

Comment: I found a solution, I add a default parameter 
`defaults: { _controller: GedApp:Default:edit, id: 0 }`

Comment: doesnt it has to look like : { 'id': 13} instead of { id: 13}

Comment: The default value fixed the issue? Doesn't make any sense :-|

Comment: @jperovic Yes I know :/, but I don't know why it's solved my problem

Comment: I am quite interested in getting to the bottom of this. Can you update your question with error message nevertheless? :)

Comment: The error message is the title of the question :D